# Saving dataframe to pdf adjust width

Tags: r, dataframe, pdf, plot, landscape

I found that `grid.table` could be used to plot a dataframe to a pdf file, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42860716/export-dataframe-to-pdf-png-in-r). I want to save a dataframe to a landscape A4 format, however it seems to not scale the data such that is nicely fits within the borders of the pdf.

**Code**

```
library(gridExtra)

set.seed(1)
strings <- c('Wow this is nice', 'I need some coffee', 'Insert something here', 'No ideas left')
table <- as.data.frame(matrix(ncol = 9, nrow = 30, data = sample(strings,30, replace = TRUE)))
pdf("test.pdf", paper = 'a4r')
grid.table(table)
dev.off()
```

**Output**
Not the whole table is shown in the pdf:
[image]

**Question** 
**How can I make sure that the dataframe is scaled to fit within the landscape A4?** I don't explicitly need `gridExtra` or the default `pdf` save, I can use any other package if these are easier to fix this.

---

**EDIT**

I came across [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15937131/print-to-pdf-file-using-grid-table-in-r-too-many-rows-to-fit-on-one-page), appareantly one can figure out the required height and width of the `tableGrob`

```
tg = gridExtra::tableGrob(table)
h = grid::convertHeight(sum(tg$heights), "mm", TRUE)
w = grid::convertWidth(sum(tg$widths), "mm", TRUE)
ggplot2::ggsave("test.pdf", tg, width=w, height=h, units = 'mm')
```

Here `h = 172.2` and `w = 444.3` which exceed the size of a standard A4, namely 210 x 279. So I know this causes the problem however still can't figure out to scale down the table to fit it on an A4.

Comment: You might try adding the argument `width=9` to your pdf statement.

Comment: @G5W Running `pdf("test.pdf", paper = 'a4r', width = 9)` did not change the output (likely since `a4r` already specifies the output pdf size)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out I could add the `scale` parameter to `ggsave`.  I wrote a simple function to get the optimal scale:

`optimal.scale <- function(w,h, wanted.w, wanted.h) max(c(w/wanted.w,  h/wanted.h))`

I added  0.1 to the scale to add a margin to the plot such that the text is not directly on the edge of the paper. Then I passed the resulting scale to `ggsave`

```
  tg = gridExtra::tableGrob(table
  h = grid::convertHeight(sum(tg$heights), "mm", TRUE)
  w = grid::convertWidth(sum(tg$widths), "mm", TRUE)
  scale = optimal.scale(w,h, 279, 210) + 0.1 #A4 = 279 x 210 in landscape 
  ggplot2::ggsave("test.pdf", tg, width = 279, height = 210, units = 'mm' , scale = scale)
```

Now my table fits on the A4:

[image]